Create a separated copy of an R closure
Is there a way to copy a closure to a new object that contains the current status of the original closure while also being separated for all upcoming changes in the environment?
I have tried to come up with a solution, but it fails with an error when I try using the contained function: Error in { : could not find function "{"
Here's a code example:
# basic incrementation closure
inc <- function() {
  i <- 0 
  
  function(x = 1) {
    i <<- i + x
    i
  }
}

copyClosure <- function(x) {
  oldEnv <- environment(x)
  
  # set up copy of x in new env
  ret <- x
  newEnv <- new.env(parent = emptyenv())
  environment(ret) <- newEnv
  
  # copy objects from old to new env
  objs <- ls(envir = oldEnv, all.names = TRUE, sorted = FALSE)
  for (ii in objs) assign(x = ii, envir = newEnv, value = get(x = ii, envir = oldEnv))
  
  return(ret)
}

# original closure object
foo <- inc()
foo(5)

bar <- copyClosure(foo)

# check if objects i are identical
identical(x = get(x = "i", envir = environment(foo)),
          y = get(x = "i", envir = environment(bar)))

# check if objects i are separated
foo(5)
identical(x = get(x = "i", envir = environment(foo)),
          y = get(x = "i", envir = environment(bar)))

# try using copied closure
bar(5)



When a function f is run the functions that are called in the body of that function, including any base functions such as {,  are looked up through the ancestors of the function f so if the ancestor is emptyenv() it won't be able to find any functions at all.

With a proper copy, ideally, I'd want to cut all ties to any ancestor though or am I wrong?

Change the parent of the new environment to match the old environment
newEnv <- new.env(parent = parent.env(oldEnv))

Then it seems to work as intended.
foo <- inc()
foo(5)
# [1] 5
bar <- copyClosure(foo)
identical(x = get(x = "i", envir = environment(foo)),
          y = get(x = "i", envir = environment(bar)))
# [1] TRUE
foo(5)
# [1] 10
identical(x = get(x = "i", envir = environment(foo)),
          y = get(x = "i", envir = environment(bar)))
# [1] FALSE
bar(5)
# [1] 10


Ok, I see that this is what @g-grothendieck was also hinting towards. I understand, that the reference to the functions is lost by setting the parent to emptyenv() since searching for the sources further up will not succeed with a disconnected emptyenv. I guess, as long as the enclosing environment of the closure is changed during the copy, there is nothing wrong with this approach? I'll accept the answer, thank you!
